# Unite elements that share the same value of a variable in a vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct

For example, I have this struct :

```
struct Time
{
char Day[10];
int pay;
int earn;
}
```

And suppose that the vector of this Time struct has the following elements:

```
vector<Time> mySelf = ({"Monday", 20, 40}, {"Tuesday", 15, 20}, {"Monday", 30, 10}, {"Tuesday", 10, 5});
```

So is there any algorithm to unite the data so that elements with the same day name will appear once and the other variables of those elements will combine together to form a new vector like this :

```
vector<Time> mySelf = ({"Monday", 50, 50}, {"Tuesday", 25, 25});
```

Comment: *So is there any algorithm to unite the data* -- You could use  a `std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, int>>` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to insert your elements to `unordered_map`, and then reconstruct a vector. Search and insertion to the map have constant-time complexity, so all the operation will be O(n), because we need to iterate over a vector twice.

```
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Time> timeMap;
    for (const auto& t : mySelf)
    {
        if (timeMap.count(t.day) == 0)
        {
            timeMap[t.day] = t;
        }
        else
        {
            timeMap[t.day].pay += t.pay;
            timeMap[t.day].earn += t.earn;
        }
    }
```

or shorter version, since `insert` already checks if the element exists and will not overwrite it:

```
    for (const auto& t : mySelf)
    {
        timeMap.insert({t.day, {t.day,0,0}});
        timeMap[t.day].pay += t.pay;
        timeMap[t.day].earn += t.earn;
    }
```

and then the vector reconstruction:

```
    std::vector<Time> result;
    result.reserve(timeMap.size());
    for (const auto&[key, val] : timeMap)
    {
        result.push_back(val);
    }
```

Alternatively you could use `std::unordered_set` but then you need some hash function for your struct. Probably you could improve it further with move semantics.

[live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GrGW5v5hc)

Comment: There is no need to check for 0 elements.  Simply call `insert` regardless of the count, and insert a Time with no pay or earn value:  `timeMap.insert({t.day, {t.day,0,0}}); timeMap[t.day].pay += t.pay; timeMap[t.day].earn += t.earn;`.  Code that checks for 0 elements in a map suspiciously looks like a Java programmer's attempt at using a C++ map/unordered_map, since Java (and probably other languages) do not default initialize the map data to 0).